# shortcodes output before content

Tags: shortcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem with short code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47062/problem-with-short-code)

**Shortcodes are broken.**

For those of you playing at home, heres an easy step by step to replicate my problem.

---

1) Open a fresh Wordpress install (3.4.2).

2) Go into twentyeleven/functions.php and add the following:

```
function test() {
echo '-TEST-';
}
add_shortcode('testshortcode', 'test');
```

3) Edit the 'hello world' post to say:

```
Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging! 
[testshortcode] 
foobar
```

4) Save and view, my results look like the following:

```
-TEST-
Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!
foobar
```

when it should look like this:

```
Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!
-TEST-
foobar
```

**What on earth is going on here?**

Comment: Instead of "echo '-TEST-';"  use "return '-TEST-';" .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Shortcode callbacks have to return, not output. So use the following:

```
function test() {
    return '-TEST-';
}
add_shortcode( 'testshortcode', 'test' );
```

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

If you have to use echo you can also do it this way(useful if there's a lot of markup & it's difficult working with strings)-

```
function test() {
    ob_start();
    echo '-TEST-';
    return ob_get_contents();
}
add_shortcode( 'testshortcode', 'test' );
```

Comment: That's interesting, it works on the clean install but doesn't work in a plugin that does the same thing, it used echo and failed like my example, but when i change it to return it still fails. Here's the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-media-tags/

Comment: I downloaded the plugin & checked it, if you replace echo with return there, it will return the content to the calling function, not to wordpress.

Comment: I just worked that out and was about to comment, if you put another return on the function the callback calls and replace the echo, it works. Cheers.

Comment: This displayed content twice for me (one before content, second on the place I wanted). I solved this by:

`function test()
{
 ob_start();
 echo '-TEST-';
 $ReturnString = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 return $ReturnString;
}`

Comment: For people that have the content displaying twice, instead of ob_get_contents, use ob_get_clean