# Shortcode output appears before post body

Tags: plugins, shortcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [short code output too early](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47062/short-code-output-too-early)

How can I insert my plugin code via shortcode inside post body in exact position?

The problem is that wp engine inserts the plugin code **BEFORE** post body all the time. Can it be fixed?

For example: I have some `[shortcode option="value"]`, that generates some text with image inside div container. When I put it inside the post **AFTER** the text, wp outputs this code:

`<div> here is my plugin code </div> <p> here is the text of the post </p>`

… and so it gets in the top of the post.

Where is my fault?

Comment: Are you using `print` or `echo` in your shortcode handler? Read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47062/short-code-output-too-early).

Comment: Yes, the problem was in `echo`'s. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have had this problem before: shortcodes shouldn't **display** any content (using `print` or  `echo`), instead `return` the content to be outputted.

If it's too much trouble converting all of your output statements, or you need to use a function that will always display the output, you can use **output buffering**. A buffer will 'catch' any `echo`'d or `print`'d content and allow you to write it to a variable.

```
function my_awesome_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    // begin output buffering
    ob_start();

    // output some text
    echo 'foo' . "bar\n";
    $greeting = 'Hello';
    printf( '%s, %s!', $greeting, 'World' );

    // end output buffering, grab the buffer contents, and empty the buffer
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'awesome', 'my_awesome_shortcode' );
```

Learn more about [Output Buffering Control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) and the different [Output Control Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) that you can use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `return` works exactly as I expected.