# how to add shortcode in wordpress container

Tags: shortcode

I develop my plugin with this code :

```
function my_function( $atts ) {
    some code
}
add_shortcode( 'myfunction_shortcode', 'my_function' );
```

I need to use my shortcode on my page or post, when I used it output code shown on top of my page.

Comment: the code of the shortcode must return the HTML code to display and not display it directly. read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to the way your shortcode is constructed.  PHP scripts are run on the server before (as) the HTML is generated.

Try buffering your shortcode ouput like this:

```
function my_function( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    // do some stuff

    $code_output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $code_output;
}
```

More info: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: thanks jam2112, I read this question too after post my question, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75554/shortcode-output-appears-before-post-body?rq=1