# add short code not working

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, template-tags

I am new to wordpress, I am creating a plugin and for the short code, I am using the short code api. But when I insert this shortcode in my page, it displayes as it is, it does not display the required output. Can asny body tell me what i am doing wrong? Am I calling or creating the function on right place or not?
Below is my code

```
function show_review() {
echo "this is a review form";
}
add_shortcode('urp_review', 'show_review');
```

I have created the file named as urp_functions.php in my plugin directory and created the above function. 
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The plugin is activated?

Comment: yes the plugin is activated

Comment: Your shortcode cannot work in its current form [due to the `echo`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47077/73).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your code seems Ok, but is your plug-in correctly installed? You have to upload your urp_functions.php in a folder inside the /wp-content/plugins/ folder and in your urp_functions.php file, you have to insert comments so it gets detected as a plugin. here is the example comment on WordPress codex :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Magic Plugin
Plugin URI: http://example.com/magic-plugin
Description: Magic Plugin performs magic
Version: 2.3
Author: Mr. Magic
Author URI: http://example.com/
*/
```

Then once you have done this, you still have to go inside your admin panel and activate the plugin! Have you done all this?

Comment: no my urp_functions.php file don't have comments :(

Comment: @user1867912  I just asked you if you have activated your plugin. This means that you A) can see it in the plugins list admin page and therefore B) _must_ have those comments to be visible. => *HOW* the heck did you activate it without the comments? WP extracts all needed data from those.

Comment: It might just have been a misunderstanding on what "activate" means. I think it has become clearer now... ;-)

Comment: @kaiser i mentioned in my comment that my urp_functions.php don't have these comments. Should i add these comments in my urp_functions.php file?

Comment: Yes, this is what I told you to do. Add the comments there and upload your file. Then your plugin will become visible in yourdomain.com/wp-admin/plugins.php, where you will be able to activate it. I think Kaiser is getting surprised that you are already coding plugins while still struggling to use them! ;-)

Comment: @barakadam the plugin was already created by some one else, I just have to add the shortcode functionality in it, plugin was working fine, I activated it and started work on it

Comment: Great, well done! Then choose kaiser or myself to vote for! This is just like activating a plugin: one click!

Comment: but my problem is still there, my shortcodes are not working when i insert them in to any page or post

Comment: Wait a second... You're saying that you hacked another/existing plugin? And this one showed already in the plugin list? Then it already has to have those comments. Please go back and edit your question with _every - even extremly minor - detail_ that we might need to know. You're doing either something pretty wrong or you're simply not telling us the truth :P I mean, _how_ are you hacking the existing plugin? Did you add code to one of its files? Which plugin is it? Did you include an additional file? If yes, then where and how, etc....

Comment: the wrong thing was, I was not writing the function in index.php file. i created a new file named as urp_functions.php and it caused problem. Now put my code in index.php and its working. Thnaks :)

Comment: Why is this question marked as the answer in its current form. This is not the solution, it should not be marked as such

Comment: @user1867912 _What_ index.php file? Was there one in the plugin? Or in WP root? Or in your theme? Or... omg. This question has gone soooo wrong.

Comment: @kaiser its was in my plugin and there were all the comments already added in it

Comment: Agree with Tom J Nowell -- this is not the solution.

Answer (score 3):

A shortcode is not supposed to echo its content, it's meant to return it

e.g.:

```
function show_review($atts) {
    return "this is a review form";
}
add_shortcode('urp_review', 'show_review');
```

The function is attached to a filter, it filters/processes shortcodes/contents.

If you do an `echo`, it prints out your code before the content has finished being processed, nevermind displayed.

Perhaps an analogy will help:

> Imagine you're eating small cakes on a plate. You go to pick one up
>   and your stomach digests it before it's even an inch above the plate.
>   It needs to follow the process, receive the food inside your body and
>   pass it along to the next organ, rather than doing it the moment
>   anything food related happens.

Comment: "Perhaps an analogy will help" ... +1 for being consistent in every place.

Comment: Who the hell downvoted this and for what reason (aside from being the right answer)?

Comment: "declares answer wrong, makes no attempt to explain why"