# Including Custom fields within the_content

Tags: php, custom-field, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields, the-content

I’m designing a site for a client and I’m using custom fields for buy links to her books. I only want buy buttons to appear for fields that contain a URL, so I’ve hooked this just below the_content:

```
<?php if( get_field('kindle') ): ?>
           <a href="<?php the_field('kindle'); ?>"><img src="url.com"></a><?php endif; ?>

<?php if( get_field('nook') ): ?>
           <a href="<?php the_field('nook'); ?>"><img src="url.com"></a><?php endif; ?>
```

This code works perfectly but I would like to be able to customize the position of the buy links a little more. I thought of creating a shortcode to insert into the content of the post, but while I can create one that includes just text, when I put the above code into the shortcode.php file, it breaks.

This is the code I'm using for shortcode.php:

```
    <?php
function buy_links(){


<?php if( get_field('kindle') ): ?>
               <a href="<?php the_field('kindle'); ?>"><img src="url.com></a><?php endif; ?>

<?php if( get_field('nook') ): ?>
               <a href="<?php the_field('nook'); ?>"><img src="url.com></a><?php endif; ?>

<?php if( get_field('kobo') ): ?>
               <a href="<?php the_field('kobo'); ?>"><img src="url.com></a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( get_field('itunes') ): ?>
               <a href="<?php the_field('itunes'); ?>"><img src="url.com></a>
<?php endif; ?>

}// End buy_links()

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [short code output too early](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47062/short-code-output-too-early)

Comment: Why hardcode URL's into your function?

Comment: Only because I'm testing right now. It will all be relative links once I know it's working

Comment: @CissyH In which **shortcode.php** file did you place this code? It is enough if you place it in **functions.php** and call the function with `add_shortcode( 'buylinks', 'buy_links' );`. Then you can use the shortcode `[buylinks]` anywhere in the post. Also "assign" the HTML code to a variable and `return` it at the end of the function.

Comment: I created a buylinks_shortcode.php file and referenced it in functions.php I thought it might be cleaner in the long run, but either would work just as well I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I thought of creating a shortcode to insert into the content of the
>   post, but while I can create one that includes just text, when I put
>   the above code into the shortcode.php file, it breaks.

Your code outputs data to the screen. You can't do that with filters like `the_content`. You need to concatenate a string and return it. Something like:

```
function the_content_cb($content) {
  $str = '';
  if( get_field('kindle') ) {
    $str .= '<a href="'.get_field('kindle').'"><img src="url.com"></a>';
  }

  if( get_field('nook') ) {
    $str .= '<a href="'.get_field('nook').'"><img src="url.com"></a>';
  }
  return $content.$str;
}
```

Note: `the_field()` is a plugin function-- Advanced Custom Fields--, as is `get_field()`.

Comment: Thanks for responding! That is getting me much closer. The code isn't breaking the site, but it's not displaying anything either.  I tried looking up get_the_field and I'm not finding anything outside ACF (which I am using).

I did find this on a blog discussing how to use custom fields conditionally. Does it tell you anything?

// display an image based on custom-field value, if it exists

    <?php $image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', true);
 
 if($image) : ?>

 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="" />

 <?php endif; ?>

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The correct ACF function is [`get_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/).

Comment: Okay!! The code works with a href="'.get_field

Thank you both so much. You saved my head from exploding right off my shoulders. Way too many hours working on this :)