# How to display html element and php string in the same line?

Tags: shortcode, css

Hope someone can help me with this.

This is my code:

```
function swh_woocommerce_store_credit_shortcode() {
    $store_credits = swh_woocommerce_get_store_credits();
    echo "<span style= 'display: inline;'>Remaining Credit:</span>";
    return wc_price($store_credits);
    
}
add_shortcode( 'swh_store_credit_total_value', 'swh_woocommerce_store_credit_shortcode' );
```

I'm trying to display echo and return in the same line.

i. e. `Remaning Credit: $80` and not

```
Remaining Credit:

$80
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [must not use use `echo` or `print` in a shortcode function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47077/73). The echoed string will be printed out immediately when the content is processed, which is almost always too early.

So in your function you should just return the string without using `echo`:

```php
function swh_woocommerce_store_credit_shortcode() {
    $store_credits = swh_woocommerce_get_store_credits();
    return "<span style= 'display: inline;'>Remaining Credit:</span>" . wc_price($store_credits);    
}
```

Comment: It worked  great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
function swh_woocommerce_store_credit_shortcode() {
    $store_credits = swh_woocommerce_get_store_credits();
    $price = wc_price($store_credits);
    echo "<span style= 'display: inline;'>Remaining Credit: {$price}</span>";
    return $price;
    
}
add_shortcode( 'swh_store_credit_total_value', 'swh_woocommerce_store_credit_shortcode' );
```

But be careful what you want to return, `wp_price` or a HTML :)